# Is there any way to use Streamcontroller in generic map?

Tags: flutter, dart, generics

## Updated Comment

- I found the package that behaves almost the same as I am trying.
  Try `event_bus` [package](https://pub.dev/packages/event_bus)

## Original Question

I am trying to make a state broadcaster that broadcasts some value to listeners via single path.
And wanna use generic to reduce duplicated logic.

The following is what I am trying.

```dart
import 'dart:async';

class StateBroadcaster {
  final _sinkMap = <Type, StreamController<dynamic>>{
    StudyTimerStatus: StreamController<StudyTimerStatus?>.broadcast(),
  };

  void notify<T>(T value) => _sinkMap[T]?.add(value);

  StreamSubscription<T> listen<T>(void Function(T) onData) {
    return (_sinkMap[T] as StreamController<T>).stream.listen(onData);
  }
}
```

But when I run this code, the runtime error comes in `(_sinkMap[T] as StreamController<T>)`.

> The following _CastError was thrown building Builder:
> type '_AsyncBroadcastStreamController<StudyTimerStatus?>' is not a subtype of type 'StreamController' in type cast

How can I fix this?

It is fine to change the code if it can reach the goal I want(broadcasting the data).

I also tried omit upcasting as follows but the compile error comes.

```dart
return _sinkMap[T].stream.listen(onData);
```

> A value of type 'StreamSubscription' can't be returned from the method 'listen' because it has a return type of 'StreamSubscription'

> The argument type 'void Function(T)' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'void Function(dynamic)?

Comment: I'm confused because `notify` seems to imply that the key/value pair in your `_sinkMap`, should make use of the same generic type. The key is the generic type `T` itself, and the value is a `StreamController<T>`. However this relationship does not appear to be the case for `final _sinkMap = <Type, StreamController<dynamic>>{StudyTimerStatus: StreamController<SOME_ENUM?>.broadcast(),}`. Based on `notify` I might instead expect `final _sinkMap = <Type, StreamController<dynamic>>{StudyTimerStatus: StreamController<StudyTimerStatus>.broadcast(),}`.

Comment: If I even understand what you are trying to do (which I'm really not sure), then I suggest you create `_sinkMap` as an empty map, and do `_sinkMap[T] ??= StreamController<T>.broadcast();` at the beginning of `notify` and `listen`. Also, be sure to pass in a type argument when calling your `listen` method.

Comment: @mmcdon20
Sorry for confusing you. the indicator `SOME_ENUM` I wrote means it can be anything. And the error message I attached is the specific case of `SOME_ENUM`.
I will edit my question. Thanks for pointing out!

Comment: @mmcdon20
I updated the code as you commented but it came out with compile error. Please check this.
https://dartpad.dev/?id=8c0e602091b3ff710053131549f2e4c6

Comment: You would still need to cast `as StreamController<T>`, see my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this should accomplish what you are asking.

If you subscribe with `listen<T>()`, then you should get the corresponding values of type `T` passed to `notify`.

```dart
import 'dart:async';

class StateBroadcaster {
  final _sinkMap = <Type, StreamController<dynamic>>{};

  void notify<T>(T value) {
    _sinkMap[T] ??= StreamController<T>.broadcast();
    _sinkMap[T]?.add(value);
  }

  StreamSubscription<T> listen<T>(void Function(T) onData) {
    _sinkMap[T] ??= StreamController<T>.broadcast();
    return (_sinkMap[T] as StreamController<T>).stream.listen(onData);
  }
}

void main() {
  final broadcaster = StateBroadcaster();
  broadcaster.listen<int>((v) => print('int: $v'));
  broadcaster.listen<String>((v) => print('String: $v'));
  broadcaster.notify(1);
  broadcaster.notify('a');
  broadcaster.notify(2);
  broadcaster.notify('b');
  broadcaster.notify(3);
  broadcaster.notify('c');
}
```

---

If you want to define the key value pairs within `_sinkMap` rather than creating the key/value pairs as needed, it should be possible, but you will get a runtime exception if you try to use a key that isn't predefined in the map.

Also, you need to decide if the stream values should be nullable or not. If you want them to be nullable, then you need to add a `?` to the type in `listen`.

```dart
import 'dart:async';

class StateBroadcaster {
  final _sinkMap = <Type, StreamController<dynamic>>{
    StudyTimerStatus: StreamController<StudyTimerStatus?>.broadcast(),
  };

  void notify<T>(T value) => _sinkMap[T]?.add(value);

  StreamSubscription<T?> listen<T>(void Function(T) onData) {
    return (_sinkMap[T] as StreamController<T?>).stream.listen(onData);
  }
}
```

If you don't want them to be nullable, then you need to remove the `?` from the type in `_sinkMap`

```dart
import 'dart:async';

class StateBroadcaster {
  final _sinkMap = <Type, StreamController<dynamic>>{
    StudyTimerStatus: StreamController<StudyTimerStatus>.broadcast(),
  };

  void notify<T>(T value) => _sinkMap[T]?.add(value);

  StreamSubscription<T> listen<T>(void Function(T) onData) {
    return (_sinkMap[T] as StreamController<T>).stream.listen(onData);
  }
}
```

Comment: It solved perfectly!
But one thing I am worried about is, I tried to explicitly represent "This can be notified or listen" but the answer cannot. Do you have any idea to this?

Comment: Do you mean, you want to only allow calling `notify`/`listen` with a handful of specific types, and disallow all other types? I don't think that can be properly expressed with dart generics. One thing you can do is constrain a generic type with extends (https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#restricting-the-parameterized-type) but this would require that all of the types you want to use extend from the same superclass.

Comment: @stateless see updated answer, as well.

Comment: Works as expected, Thanks for the answer!